# How to sort records by association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

How to order records by one of its associated models? In code below when accessing `.box_chocolates` association I need it to return records ordered by `Chocolate#name`:

```
b = Box.first
b.box_chocolates # <-- records must be ordered by Chocolate#name
```

Models structure:

```
class Box < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :box_chocolates # <--- ???
end

class BoxChocolate < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :box
  belongs_to :chocolate
end

# id    :integer
# name  :string
class Chocolate < ApplicationRecord      
end
```

I created a custom method in Box class but I don't like how it works - it uses Ruby to sort records instead of SQL query:

```
def ordered_box_chocolates
   box_chocolates.sort { |a, b| a.chocolate.name <=> b.chocolate.name }
end
```

I know that I can specify ordering in `has_many` like in code below, but it does not work:

```
class Box < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :box_chocolates, -> { order("chocolate.name") }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b.box_chocolates.joins(:chocolate).order("chocolates.name asc")`

Comment: While your code may provide the answer to the question, please add context around it so others will have some idea what it does and why it is there.

Comment: The problem with my code was that I used "chocolate.name" instead of "chocolates.name". Thanks!

Comment: @yaru you mean `has_many :box_chocolates, -> { order("chocolates.name") }` is working for you?

Comment: no, I mean that your line is working for me as it is. Not as a part of has_many statement.

Answer (score 2):

you can create scope or method in box as sample below

```
class Box < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :box_chocolates 

  def self.box_chocolates_ordered
    joins(box_chocolates: :chocolate).order('chocolates.name')
      # you have to use table name in plural form (chocolates)
  end
end

b = Box.first
b.box_chocolates_ordered
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following :

```
has_many :box_chocolates, -> { order 'chocolates.name' }, through: :chocolate
```

Comment: This is a good approach, though I believe it should be the other way around: `has_many :chocolates, through: :box_chocolates, etc...`, no?

Comment: As per conventions, Yes! But as per given code snippet, what exactly the person needs to do.

Comment: @DhanashriJoshi getting `ArgumentError: Unknown key: :order.`

Comment: @DhanashriJoshi no still getting  `syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>`

Comment: has_many :box_chocolates, -> {  order 'chocolates.name'  }, through: :chocolate

Comment: @DhanashriJoshi don't edit it like a hit and try :(